# my mandelbrot set outputs wired image

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, opengl

I am trying to create a mandelbrot image using c++/opengl.  Below is the simple code that i have came up with so far and the image that comes out:

[image]

```
 #include<GL/gl.h>
 #include <GL/glu.h>
 #include <GL/glut.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 double dividecubesby  = 300;
 const double left = -2.0;
 const double right = 2.0;
 const double bottom = -2.0;
 const double top = 2.0;
 int maxiteration = 90;

 int mandtest(double Cr, double Ci){

   double Zr = 0.0;
   double Zi = 0.0;
   int times = 0;

   Zr = Zr+Cr;
   Zi = Zi+Ci;

      while ((((Zr*Zr)+(Zi*Zi))<4) && (times < maxiteration)){


        Zr = (Zr*Zr)-(Zi*Zi);
        Zi = 2*Zr*Zi;
        Zr = Zr+Cr;
        Zi = Zi+Ci;                
        times = times+1;  

      }
 return times;



void display(void)
{
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        double real = left;//this is the real part of  the order-pair in the cube
        double image = top;// this is the image part of the order-pair in the cube
        double deltax = ((right - left)/(dividecubesby));//this means 4/300
        double deltay = ((top- bottom)/(dividecubesby));// this means 4/300

glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    for(double x= left;x<=right;x += deltax ){


        for(double y= bottom; y<=top;y +=  deltay ){

            if((mandtest(x,y))==maxiteration){

                glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f); 
                            glVertex2f(x,y);

            }

            else {
                glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,(float)mandtest(x,y)/maxiteration);
                                    glVertex2f(x,y);
            }

        }
    }
    glEnd();

glFlush();

}

void init(void)
{
//select clearing (background) color
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        //initialize viewing values 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
//glortho(left,right,bottom,top,near,far)
    gluOrtho2D(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{   
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(dividecubesby,dividecubesby);
glutCreateWindow("A Simple OpenGL Windows Application with GLUT");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've done it with Java: http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2011/03/mandelbrot-set.html.  Check out the code and see if it helps you.

Comment: C++ has std::complex if you'd rather not manually handle the real and imaginary components.

Comment: kool bames i will surely try ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
    Zr = (Zr*Zr)-(Zi*Zi);
    Zi = 2*Zr*Zi;
    Zr = Zr+Cr;
    Zi = Zi+Ci;
```

You use the new `Zr` to calculate `Zi`, that yields wrong results, make it

```
    double temp = (Zr*Zr)-(Zi*Zi);
    Zi = 2*Zr*Zi;
    Zr = temp+Cr;
    Zi = Zi+Ci;
```

to get better results:

[image]

Comment: I tried that but still the same image ... :( thank you for the response thought :)

Comment: Ah, well, that was the obvious error. If that doesn't help (you ought to make that change nevertheless, you won't ever get a correct picture with a wrong iteration), there must be something else. Let's see if I find something.

Comment: @gunda Oops, I made the same mistake, I was too replace-happy. Fixed now, and it produces a nice enough picture :)

Comment: wow !!!! Daniel ... i owe big time ... you are my hero!!%%#$@#$!@!#!@#!@#!@#!@#!@#!@!@#!@#   thank you sooooo mucchhhhhhhh ...

Comment: Always happy to help. And now I have to play a bit with different viewports :)

Comment: And now for some escape time coloring.

Comment: OpenMP will give you a painless but significant performance increase.

Comment: I am currently trying use hpx